# Como deixar dinamico a configuração do .package no flutter

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio-code, flutter, dart

Como deixar dinamico a configuração do .package no flutter, por padrão da minha maquina(Windows) fica assim:

async:file:///C:/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-2.2.0/lib/

mas gostaria de uma maneira de deixar dinâmica para abrir o projeto em outros sistemas como Linux ou MAC.

Comment: nao tem como , se vc abrir no android studio ele faz as modicicacoes pra vc, o que voce pode fazer(se necessario) eh criar multiplos .packages => .package(padrao), .package_mac e ai a pessoa que for abrir no mac renomeia o arquivo _mar para .package

Comment: qual a necessidade que você vê em deixar isso dinâmico, ou até mesmo se preocupar com esta pasta? Em teoria ela é problema do próprio framework e não deve ser versionada (para usar em diferentes SOs)

Comment: Na verdade ela orgniza os lib a partir da config do flutter na maquina do dev. A então com o comando "flutter pub get" resolve o problema.